# Removing unencessary border around image input

Tags: html, css

I am inserting an image as an html button, however the image has a black border around it, how do i remove this black border.  I did not set a border pixel at all

```
     <div class="homeButton"><input type="image" src="/images/signInButton1.png"  name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Login" width="900" ></input></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#submit_button { border: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

with inline stiles

```
<input type="image" src="/images/signInButton1.png"  name="submit" id="submit_button" value="Login" width="900" style="border-style:none;"></input>
```

`border-style:none` will override all other border related styles for that element.